# How to use the gdal.Warp function with options?

Tags: python, gdal

I try to use the `gdal.Warp` function with options :

```py
# align GFC tree cover with segments 
glad_raw = pm.getDwnDir() + aoi_name + '_treecover2010.tif'
glad_aligned = pm.getDwnDir() + aoi_name + '_treecover2010_aligned.tif'
    
if not os.path.isfile(mask): 
    return 'No treecover file'
    
options = gdal.WarpOptions(
    xRes             = res['x'], 
    yRes             = res['y'], 
    creationOptions  = "COMPRESS=LZW", 
    outputBounds     = [int(v) for v,i in enumerate(bb)],
    dstSRS           = proj
    #options          = 'overwrite'
)
ds = gdal.Warp(glad_aligned, glad_raw, options)
ds = None
```

but I get the following error :

> TypeError: Warp() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

strange because the `help(gdal.warp)` gave me `Warp(destNameOrDestDS, srcDSOrSrcDSTab, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This means that the options argument is keyword argument and not positional. Keyword arguments are given to a function as gdal.Warp(positional, positional, keyword=keyword). So input and output are positional and have to be prvovided only in correct order, and keyword has to be provided using keyword.

However you do not have to provide options as gdal.WarpOptions. You can provide each argument as individual keyword argument like below:

```
gdal.Warp(OutDS, inFile, dstSRS = outSrs, dstNodata = nodata, xRes=1000, yRes=1000)
```

Comment: yes but I wanted to use `gdal.WarpOption` object. So for me the solution is  `ds = gdal.Warp(glad_aligned, glad_raw, options=options)`

Comment: Yes, options is a keyword to be used. Also if you use options all other kwargs will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do the following which personally I think is cleaner..

```
options = {
  # "format": "GTiff",
    "xRes": res['x'],
    "yRes": res['y'],
    "compressionOptions": "COMPRESS=LZW",
    "outputBounds": [int(v) for v,i in enumerate(bb)],
    "dstSRS": proj,
  # "resampleAlg": "near",
  # "outputType": gdal.GDT_Int32
}

ds = gdal.Warp(glad_aligned, glad_raw, **options)
del ds
```